# Can't access application from localhost Docker-compose

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, containers, mern

I created a MERN app authentication system,
This is my backend Dockerfile, the backend is written with express js.

```
FROM node:lts-buster-slim AS development
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/package.json
RUN yarn install
COPY . /usr/src/app
EXPOSE 3000
```

and this is my frontend Dockerfile, the frontend written with react js, with Vite.

```
FROM node
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json .
RUN yarn install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 5173
```

And finally, this is the docker-compose file.

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  backend:
    restart: always
    command: yarn dev
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    build:
      context: backend
      target: development
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    depends_on:
      - mongo
  frontend:
    build: frontend
    command: yarn dev
    ports:
      - "5173:5173"
    volumes:
      - ./frontend/:/app
    depends_on:
      - backend
  mongo:
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    container_name: mongo-Container
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=$USERNAME
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=$PASSWORD
    image: mongo
```

After I run docker-compose up, I get no errors and the prompt from my backend that express has successfully opened a connection with MongoDB. and that the Vite React application is running on port 5173. But I get nothing when I try to access the application on port 5173.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you're missing the host and port in `vite.config.js`:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  server: {
    host: true,
    port: 5173, // Port used by docker container
    strictPort: true,
     watch: {
       usePolling: true
     }
  }
 })
```

Comment: Works fine for me, thanks ! (linux, docker, laravel10, livewire, MaryUI)